# What do I need to do to develop and deploy a .net dll which exposes COM classes and is registered

Tags: .net, dll, com, fuslogvw

I have already developed a .NET assembly which I register to the GAC.  This assembly is used by my application and by 4 Office Addins.

I then needed to have a COM interfece for my Office Addins which my Application could also use. I have created a new .dll in .net which exposes COM interfaces.  This .dll currently is referenced by my office addins.  It is also referenced by the assembly in the GAC.

The problem I have is that I cannot get my office Addins to find the COM dll once deployed on a target machine.

The COM dll is not being added to the GAC it is simply in its own folder within the Application's folder.  I am using \codebase and I can see the classes in the registry have a codebase key and they point to the right path.

Fuslogvw confirms it does not work but does not help me any further.

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = MyComConnect, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c0fb9ef9db76b1e7
(Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/MyApp/MyAppAddins/MyAppOutlook/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = OUTLOOK.EXE
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/MyApp/MyAppAddins/MyAppOutlook/MyComConnect.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/MyApp/MyAppAddins/MyAppOutlook/MyComConnect/MyComConnect.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/MyApp/MyAppAddins/MyAppOutlook/MyComConnect.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/MyApp/MyAppAddins/MyAppOutlook/MyComConnect/MyComConnect.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

How or what do I need to do to work out what is going wrong?

A couple of points;

1. On the development machine I have a folder with the  COM .dll saved in it and this is what I reference in my projects
2. On build all my projects copy this COM  .dll to the bin folder
3. I do not copy the COM  .dll with each project in my installation project.
4. In my installation project I have only one folder with the COM .dll in it and register it with \codebase which I thought meant that every project would find it.

Comment: This has nothing to do with COM, it is just a normal assembly reference.  If you don't put it in the GAC nor in the AppBase directory then the CLR has no hope of finding it.  If you absolutely want to do it this way (?) then your add-in has to help by subscribing the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve event.

Comment: Thank you Hans. I thought adding codebase keys helped the CLR find it. So at the risk of asking a question I now register my .dll to the GAC and also add the registry keys for COM (eg. Heat.exe and WIX) but without the codebase as the dll is in the GAC it will now be found.

Comment: There is no point in registering it at all since those registry keys will never be used, the GAC is enough.

Comment: One thing I am doing is the Com class should be usable by Office / VBA which requires the TLB.  So I think I do need the registry in this case or is there another way? I tried just adding the dll to the GAC but then I cannot choose my class as a reference in VBA.